# Partitioning array elements into two subsets

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, array

Problem:

> Given a randomly ordered array of *n*-elements, partition the elements
>   into two subsets such that elements <= x are in one subset and elements
>
> > x are in the other subset.
>
> One way to do this is to sort the array in ascending order. But with
>   this solution we actually ordered the array in addition to partition.
>   Also sort is costly.
>
> For example, let's take this array \$[37,36,27,11,15,12,34,29,4,10]\$
>   and partition value is `17`.
>
> So the array after partition should be
>   \$[10,4,12,11,15,27,34.29.36,37]\$
>
> Comparing these two data sets we can see that elements from left side
>   greater than 17 must be moved to right side and at the right side
>   elements less than 17 to left side.
>
> Initially we do not know how many elements are less than < 17. One
>   way to solve this, pass through the array and count the number of
>   elements less than 17. Once we know the partition value (here it is
>   15), then make another pass through the array to make the exchange.
>   But this is \$0(n^2)\$.
>
> We need to find a solution where this can be done with only pass
>   through the array. Looking at these data sets we can find that even if
>   we do not know the partition value(here it is 17), 37 can be exchanged
>   with 10, 36 can be exchanged with 4 and so on.
>
> This is something like left partition is growing to right and right is
>   growing to left.
>
> ```
> | Left Partition ->    ||   <- Right Partition |
> ^                    ^                       ^
> i=0            partition point           j=n (length of array)
> ```
>
> So we get the basic mechanism to exchange, while two partitions have
>   not met do
>
> 1. Extend the left and right partitions inward exchanging wrongly  placed elements.
> 2. Exchange can be done by the standard technique
>
>    ```
>    t = a[i];
>    a[i] = a[j];
>    t = a[j];
>    ```
> 3. Moving inwards from left and right can be done by,
>
>    from left to right: `while(a[i] <= x) i = i + 1;`
>
>    from right to left: `while(x < a[j]) j = j - 1;`
>
>    where `a` is the array, `i` is the starting index 0, `j` is last index
>      that is the length of the array.
>
> One case is, initially we don't know `a[i]` and `a[j]` should be
>   exchanged since there is no initial move inwards from the left and
>   right to check if an exchange is really necessary. we can overcome
>   this by placing a check before passing through the array:
>
> ```
> while(a[i] <= x) i = i + 1;
> while(x < a[j]) j = j - 1;
> ```
>
> Algorithm (it is based on R. G. Dromey's How to solve it by computer):
>
> 1. Establish an array \$a[1...n]\$ and partition value `x`.
> 2. Move the two partitions towards each other until a wrongly placed pair of    elements is encountered.
> 3. While two partitions have not met or crossed do
>
>    - exchange wrongly placed pairs and extend both partitions inwards    by one element.
>    - extend left partition while elements less than or equal to x
>    - extend right partition while elements greater than x
> 4. Print partitioning index p and partitioned array.

Here is my solution:

```
public class PartitionArray {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[] elements = {37, 36, 27, 11, 15, 12, 34, 29, 4, 10};

    int x = 17;
    int p = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = elements.length - 1;

    while (elements[i] <= x && i < j) i = i +1;
    while (x < elements[j] && i < j) j = j - 1;

    int tmp;

    while (i < j) {
      tmp = elements[i];
      elements[i] = elements[j];
      elements[j] = tmp;

      i = i + 1;
      j = j - 1;

      while (elements[i] <= x && i < j) i = i +1;
      while (x < elements[j] && i < j) j = j - 1;

      p = j;
    }

    print("P: " + elements[p]);
    print("Partitioned Array: " + Arrays.toString(elements));
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically it's still `O(n)`.  A second pass is `O(2n) == O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is a homework for sort algorithm study :

- Manage `ArrayList` and load your list of number,
- put all `number<=x` in a new ArrayList,
- delete them from the original ArrayList,
- finish with `.addAll(..),` to concatenate if needed.

Knowing that VM is optmized, it would be interesting to compare performance of this approach with your one.

Comment: Inserting or deleting an element from an ArrayList is `O(N)` (if we exclude special cases).